# Function that scan through file and set string and integer parameter to finding the 5 largest numbers in the text file C++

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, c++17

I made a function that sets the integer and string parameter to find the highest 5 scores and the names of 5 players respectively.

With the sort function, I figured out to print the 5 highest scores :

`std::sort(highscore, highscore + 5, greater<int>());`

But names of player left the same.

For example:

Input:

```
Mark 
500
Sarah 
200
Stan 
250
Michelle 
1000
Franc
4900
```

Output: (As you see the name is still the same)

```
Mark
4900
Sarah
1000
Stan
500
Michelle
250
Franc
200
```

By what procedure, I could swap the names in order of scores respectively?

Comment: Store the data in a `struct` or a `class`, not as individual items as you're doing now.  Also on a side note -- if the number of items in the file is very large, the better way to do this is to not sort, but to maintain a min-heap of 5 elements.  Doing that makes the difference between storing thousands or millions of names and having to sort them, and storing only 5 names.

Comment: Instead of sort, simple function will do?

Comment: Do you know what `struct` is?  If you do, then `struct info { std::string name; int score; };` and create an array of structs, then sort the struct based on the score.  It would also help if you actually posted your code.

Comment: You are sorting the first 5 items, you need to sort everything and take 5.

Answer (score 2):

Use a custom type

```
struct player {
    std::string name;
    int score;
};
```

Then sort a `std::vector<player>` with respect to score, for example via

```
auto cmp_score = [](const player& a, const player& b) { return a.score < b.score; };
std::sort(players.begin(),players.end(),cmp_score);
```

As mentioned in a comment, using a min-heap of 5 elements avoids to keep all players from the file in memory.